# Stream.Read always returning 0

Tags: asp.net, filestream, memorystream, asyncfileupload

We are using Asyncfileupload control of asp.net to upload the file, the same is not working we have debugged and found this code:

```
input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

returning 0.

The entire code is like this:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try to debug and have a look at `input.Length` I guess it is zero as well?

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanels? Try your code without one, AsyncFileUpload has trouble with UpdatePanels, I'm guessing your file upload control is empty when you postback, try this If AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile Then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stream.Read may return 0 if you are at end of the byte array or your network connection is broken. You can try this line of code to make sure:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
input.Position=0;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```